# MVC4 Model in View issue: in debug mode Model is missing details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, ef-code-first

I encountered a very strange (and annoying) issue:
in MVC 4 web application while loading data from the database and using a foreach on the Model within the view:

```
@foreach (var meeting in Model)
```

i have a breakpoint in the method's beginning and examining the object meeting i see that it misses some data (reference to other tables). if I open (+) other object within meeting the missing data appears.

Why?

Thanks!

here is my controller method:

```
        public ActionResult GetMeetingMR(int id = 0)
    {
        var meetingPurpose = db.MeetingPurposes.ToList();
        ViewBag.MeetingPurpose = new SelectList(meetingPurpose, "MeetingPurposeID", "MeetingPurposeName");
        ViewBag.MRID = id;
        List<Meeting> meetings = (db.MortgageRequests.Find(id)).Meetings.ToList();
        return View(meetings);

    }
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with MVC4 but with how you use EF to load your data from the database. What you experience is the effect of the lazy loading in Entity-Framework. So please post your data loading code to let us help you.

Comment: Hi @nemesv i just edited the question with the code from my controller. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Including your title in your question, my guess is you do not experience the problem (yet) without the debugger attached.
As others have commented it is due to `LazyLoading`.
The problem may occur sometimes because while rendering the `View` the entities container is being disposed, most probably because it is collected by the GarbageCollector which calls the destructor of the container.
If you wish to access the entities on your `View` you can use `Include` on the `ObjectSet`.
Let's say `MeetingPurposes` has an associated `EntitySet` of `Dates`:
If you wish to include them in the loadoperation you can do the following:
`db.MeetingPurposes.Include("Dates").ToList();`

```
public ActionResult GetMeetingMR(int id = 0)
{
    //Load the MeetingPurposes including their dates
    var meetingPurpose = db.MeetingPurposes.Include("Dates").ToList();
    ViewBag.MeetingPurpose = new SelectList(meetingPurpose,
                                            "MeetingPurposeID",
                                            "MeetingPurposeName");
    ViewBag.MRID = id;
    List<Meeting> meetings = (db.MortgageRequests.Find(id)).Meetings.ToList();
    return View(meetings);
}
```

If you wish to do this for `Meetings` and Meetings has an `EntitySet` of `Dates` you could do:

```
public ActionResult GetMeetingMR(int id = 0)
{
    var meetingPurpose = db.MeetingPurposes.ToList();
    ViewBag.MeetingPurpose = new SelectList(meetingPurpose,
                                            "MeetingPurposeID",
                                            "MeetingPurposeName");
    ViewBag.MRID = id;
    var meetings = (from mee in db.Meetings.Include("Dates")
                    join mga in dbo.MortgageRequests.Where(m => m.Id == id)
                    on mee.MortgageRequestID equals mga.ID
                    select mee).ToList();
    return View(meetings);
}
```

Not really sure what your `Find` extension method is so I used a `Where` on `MortgageRequests`.

Comment: Hi @Silvermind, thank you for your answer. I have tried so far these options:
`db.Meetings.Include(m => m.MortgageRequest.Meetings).Where(m => m.MortgageRequest.MortgageRequestID == id).ToList()`
and: `db.MortgageRequests.Include(m => m.Meetings).Where(m => m.MortgageRequestID == id).First().Meetings.ToList();`
Still I don't get the data in the object.
In you second example do you create another DBContext dbo?

Comment: @Shlo What is the name of the Navigation property you would like to access? I'm not creating a DbContext, I assume you already had one.

Comment: I try to access two navigation properties: SetToUser and SetByUser. these properties are reference to UserProfile. I do have a dbContext. thanks.

Comment: I changed my query to this: `db.Meetings.Include(m => m.SetByUser).Where(m => m.MortgageRequest.MortgageRequestID == id).ToList();` and it works. I think it is because I included the navigation property in the query?